# My web-page doesn't seem to be available on other computers (the www)

Tags: apache-2.2, fedora

So, I thought I had everything covered to get my webpage (just a couple of lines of html) available to the www, but it seems i'm missing something and I really have no idea what.

I set up my apache web server (on my fedora 13 box) according to these instructions:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_a_Fedora_Linux_Based_Web_Server
I even created the sample index.html file that's described in the instructions. I can get to the webpage from my own machine by going to http://127.0.0.1/.

At first, my fiance couldn't access the page (I've associated my domain name with my dynamic IP address according to these instructions: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_a_Fedora_Linux_Based_Web_Server#Requirements_for_Configuring_a_Web_Server) so I configured my firewall to allow http traffic on port 80.

HOWEVER, I'm STILL not able to access the page from other machines.
Any help would be appreciated!

Update: I've gotten some answers asking me to try using the 192.168.1.X ip address from a different computer. This was SUCCESSFUL, but i'm not sure what to do next to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Are you able to ping your machine from elsewhere? Have you verified that your domain resolves to your IP address?

Comment: If it's the domain name in your user profile, it looks like it's not getting past your router. When you opened port 80, did you also assign the private IP address of your server as the one that would be handling the traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all these computers on the same LAN as the web server? If so attempt to access the servers webpage using the private IP address associated with that server (e.g. http://192.168.1.X), do this from the browser of another computer on the local LAN.

If that doesn't work then we know it's not DNS or router related. It would likely be an issue local to the web server. In which case make sure iptables is initially disabled and read the webserver log files to see if any requests are even getting to the daemon. Also, attempt to telnet to port 80 on the webserver from the other computers.

No use in including any DNS related issues or possible routing issues until AFTER you have verified the site is accessible on the local LAN.

If it is accessible, then it's like either a DNS issue and/or a port forwarding issue on the router.

Comment: can't choose as the correct answer because my account hasn't been associated with my question yet. But it looks like this must be a DNS issue since I can access the server from a different machine on the same LAN.

Comment: Any thoughts on what my NEXT steps should be?

Comment: thanks, sounds like I should move this off my home network to a machine that's configured for internet traffic. I thought it'd be simpler to host a stupid toy webpage off my laptop.

Comment: What type of router and ISP do you have? If it's DSL then you may need to configure the DSL modem for port-forwarding and/or a DMZ as well as any router you have. If you have cable then likely only the router will need to be configured. I've had good luck just googling for port-forwarding and the router model. You should be able to bring your router up via it's web interface by using the gateway address in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

I assume another PC is on the same LAN. How did u access ur web page from another PC? 127.0.0.1 is special address for accessing one own machine. So u have to access via ur private address which should be 192.168.x.x. U can ifconfig to check the address.

But If you want your web to be accessible from the internet u will need to config port forwarding on your router modem. Also, u might want to do dynamic DNS. Google that out for more.

Comment: How can I learn more about configuring port-forwarding?

Comment: Please spell out the words "you" and "your". It's not hard to type two more letters.

Comment: I was typing that on my mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Your updated answer strongly implies that there's no routing between your outside dynamic address, which is probably attached to a router/firewall box. That's normal, and is part of how these boxes keep your home network safe — there's no way in. You need to set up port forwarding from your router to your 192.168.1.X address. That's configured differently for different models — what do you have?

And you'll want to make your web server system get its IP address statically, because generally the forwardings are simply done by IP address, and if it changes, you don't want your incoming port 80 traffic hitting a different system.

This makes this a lot more a home networking question than a Server Fault one, by the way.....